# Update textbox from cpp

Tags: visual-c++, managed-c++

I still get error after build solution. Please help.
The error is :1>test.cpp(15): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '->'

//Form1.h

```
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{

    public:
    static Form1^ myForm1;
Form1(void)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    myForm1 = this;
    //
    //TODO: Add the constructor code here
    //
}
}
```

In cpp file:

```
Form1^ myform1 = gcnew Form1();
Form1::myForm1->textBox1->Text = L" FROM the main.cpp ";
```

Comment: Where and how is the text box defined? Can you provide full code example?

Comment: textBox1 is private, so it depends "where in the cpp file" you're trying to do that. Why are using a static form object?

Comment: private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
 protected: 
 private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1

Comment: yes, it is in private. So, how i suppose to update the textbox in cpp file? Please help me to correct it.